# apostrophe in username

Tags: ee2

Anyone able to provide what needs to be change in the core to allow this?

I was able to allow it in the email field by changing the regex in email_helper.php but I am using zoo visitor and have email as username set and username is not allowing it.

I have read about every post on the matter out there but they are all for older versions of EE. I am running 2.8.

Please help, this might be a deal breaker for me at this point.

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be allowing apostrophe's in the username field.

But assuming that you have some strange one-off reasoning behind it, you'll need to modify the logic involved with validating the username. The function you'll need to modify can be found in:

/system/expressionengine/libraries/EE_Form_validation.php

Simply look for this function:

```
function valid_username()
```

and modify it accordingly. Mine was on line 109.